# Is uniform continuous distribution over a set $A$ a definition , or can it be seen in term of Uniform distribution on an interval?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Wikipedia gives that ,the density of a uniform continuous distribution on a set $A$ is given by $$\frac{1}{\lambda(A)}\mathbb{1}_A$$
Where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function of $A$, ands $\lambda(A)$ a lebesgue measure of $A$ (depending of the dimension of the object we measure)

For example , if we consider the uniform continuous distribution on the unitary disk , we have :
$$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\mathbb{1}_D(x,y)  $$
If X,Y relates to the cartesian coordinates.

**More precisely the question is , if being asked to give the density of the uniform law over the unitary disk for example , does the result comes from the definition we given in a first place , or would we be supposed to do a calculus using only the very known density of an uniform density on an interval $\left[a,b\right]$ ?**

Comment: The "result" comes from the Lebesgue measure you mentioned in the first place...

Comment: Can you give a link to that statement in Wikipedia?

Comment: @Kurt.G , the result I tried to quote is stated on wikipedia french , but in wikipedia EN i think the equivalent is here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) at paragraph "Generalization to Borel sets"

Comment: The [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_uniforme_continue#Loi_uniforme_sur_l'ensemble_A) Wikipedia has more. It simply says that for any Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R^d$ with finite and strictly positive Lebesgue measure $\lambda(A)$ the continuous uniform distribution on $A$ is the one that has density $f(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda(A)}\chi_A(x)\,.$ You have correctly spelled this out for $A$ being the unit disk. Perhaps you can now answer the question yourself if this has anything to do with the uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$ ?